# Opening files with the name of a variable

Tags: python

I am using a Markov chain. When the chain arrives at a particular state, two files (a .png and an .mp3) need to open.

`s` is the current state of the chain, an integer from 1-59.

I can't seem to find how to open the file with the same number as 's'.

I'm sure it has something to do with `%str` formatting, but I can't seem to implement it.

```
img = Image.open('/.../.../s.png')
img.show()
```

Comment: `f"/.../.../{s}.png"`

Comment: @redFur Will only work if OP is using Python 3.6, for which I don't see any indication

Comment: Don't see any indication that OP is not using Python 3.6 )

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following line in your code:

```
img = Image.open('/.../.../{0}.png'.format(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format a string using a variable like this

```
>>> s = 10
>>> '/path/to/file/{}.png'.format(s)
'/path/to/file/10.png'
```